# What is making "at" in AIX add a "cd /some/path/here" prior to my explicit commands?

Tags: aix, cd-command, at

When I execute the following command:

```
cd /some/path/here
at -t 201409301100
ls -al
<CTRL-D>
at -lov
```

I get the following output:

```
========================
myusername.1411755840.a   Mon Sep 30 11:00:00 CDT 2014
========================
cd /some/path/here
ls -al
```

What is causing the `cd /some/path/here` command to appear?  Other users on the same system are not seeing this behavior.

I'm using KornShell in AIX 6.1.

My `.envfile` contains:

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
        case `who am i | awk '{print $1}'` in
                'myusername')
                        #set the prompt to include the date and time
                        #set -o allexport
                        unset _Y _M _D _h _m _s
                        eval $(date "+_Y=%Y;_M=%m;_D=%d;_h=%H;_m=%M;_s=%S")
                        ((SECONDS = 3600*${_h#0}+60*${_m#0}+${_s#0}))
                        typeset -Z2 _h _m _s
                        _tsub="(_m=(SECONDS/60%60)) == (_h=(SECONDS/3600%24)) + (_s=(SECONDS%60))"
                        #_timehm='${_x[_tsub]}$_h:${_m}'
                        #_timehms='${_x[_tsub]}$_h:$_m:${_s}'
                        _timedhms=$_Y'/'$_M'/'$_D" "'${_x[_tsub]}$_h:$_m:${_s}'
                        _hn=`hostname`
                        typeset -u _hn
                        _un=`whoami | awk '{print $1}'`
                        typeset -u _un
                        export PS1="$_timedhms
"'['$_un']'$_hn':${PWD#$HOME/} $ '
                        #set +o allexport
                ;;
                *)
                ;;
        esac
fi
```

Comment: put a `pwd` at the top of the script, now are the outputs equal... does pwd also equal some path here?

Comment: yes, it appears the `pwd` is getting inserted at the start of the `at`'d commands

Comment: is it a script or just the at command?

Comment: this behavior occurs when I type the `at` command at the prompt.  It is *not* embedded in a script.  Other users are not seeing this behavior.  I've added the contents of the `.envfile`

Comment: Hmm, as a bit of debugging, clear out you environment file and reload your shell.  If the cd still appears, its not coming from the file.

Answer (score 2):

An at job is executed in the directory where the `at` command was called.

Different implementations achieve that in different ways. It happens that yours does it by putting a `cd` command at the start of the job, before your code.

An at job is also executed in the same environment as when the `at` command was called, and with the same umask. AIX implements environment and umask preservation in some other way (I don't know how).